# Compose Navigation: How Can Users Launch The Application on Unexpected Screens?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Why can the user launch the application on a screen that is deeper in our navigation hierarchy?

Using Jetpack Compose Navigation. We are seeing crashes in the app which we are logging in Crashlytics. We are also recording screen views which we can see in the crash event's logs. This allows us to see where the user has been in the app since launch.

We are crashing because we rely on some data stored in memory in a singleton repository. This would be fine if the user went through the only way we've specified to get onto that screen, however from the logs we can see that the session starts and they're immediately on the screen somehow.

See below for a screenshot of the firebase crash report logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible and this happens. Basically the user minimized the app on the deeper screen, left it for some time, system killed your app (process death), then user launched the app again: navigation component saved last visible screen and restored it automatically on re-launch.

Looks like you need to redesign the app a little bit, e.g. if the screen needs some data from previous screen, pass it as a screen argument instead saving in repository. The screen arguments will survive process death.

Read about `onSaveInstanceState` and `SavedStateHandle`.

Comment: What I don't like about this is my screen navigation is getting stupidly complicated with a lot of parameters just passed between screens. Also, for more complex types, I either need to break them down into their primitives and pass as nav arguments or persist them to storage.

Comment: In general we should pass only id of an entity, and the receiving screen will load the required object from repository on its own. This is right solution to list -> details screen and similar. For other kind of stuff, like multi step screens, you can consider shared view model with SavedStateHandle to store data that should not be lost on process death. Another idea is to detect on each screen that some data is missing due to process death and just navigate back.